# POST request and 405 error in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, http-status-code-405, urlfetch

I have some troubles with headers in GAS. I use an API which require Cookie for POST requests. When, i try it with Postman it works but with the script I still receive an 405 error :/

First of all, I make a login request which return a cookie like this one : `JSESSIONID=D55B09A9076826AB6FC35B79B803C3F4; Path=/lambdapath; Secure; HttpOnly,authash=29cb2e5466f8a923da588fa55914fd72`

Then, I build a POST request like this :

```
function createObject(body, cookie) {
  var options = {
    'method': 'post',
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'Cookie': cookie,
    'payload' : JSON.stringify(body)
  }
  var header = { 'headers': options }
  try {
   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://urlOftheAPI/create", header); 
    Logger.log('Saved one item :' + response.getResponseCode())
    return response.getResponseCode();
  } catch(err) {
    throw new Error(err); 
  }
}
```

When I log the header it returns this :

```
"headers": {
    "method": "post",
    "contentType": "application/json",
    "Cookie": "JSESSIONID=D55B09A9076826AB6FC35B79B803C3F4; Path=/lambdapath; Secure; HttpOnly,authash=29cb2e5466f8a923da588fa55914fd72",
    "payload": "{\"foo\":\"bar\"}"
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help :)

## EDIT

Thanks to @DimuDesign. It works when passing options with this format :

```
 var options = {
    'method': 'post',
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'headers': {
      'cookie': 'JSESSIONID=D55B09A9076826AB6FC35B79B803C3F4; Path=/lambdapath; Secure; HttpOnly,authash=29cb2e5466f8a923da588fa55914fd72'
    },
    'payload' : JSON.stringify(body)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your call to `UrlFetchApp.fetch` is not properly formatted. Check the following reference documentation for the correct syntax:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object)

**Tip**: The `headers` object is an *advanced* parameter of the `options` object.

Comment: I updated my question. I made a mistake when i wrote it :/ The code is well written in my script but it doesn't work

Comment: @PierreJones Its still wrong (see the tip I added to my answer). Check the documentation linked in my answer, it will help you clear up the issues you're having with syntax.

Comment: It works :) you're right. With this structure :
 `var options = {
    'method': 'post',
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'headers': {
      'cookie': cookie
    },
    'payload' : JSON.stringify(body)
  }`

Comment: @PierreJones Viola! :) Always reference canonical documentation before doing anything else...saves you a lot of time in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to fetch url:

```
var url = 'https://api.example.com/';
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
var result = data.headers.Cookie;
return result;
```

Comment: The problem is not how can I intercept the cookie but how can I pass it in the headers with contenType ... 
Also, I've tried your code to intercept it but it doesn't work. When I log to the API, it doesn't return body so `JSON.parse(response.getContentText());` failed ;)